# How to pass two variables on keyup?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Stuck on this one. I would like to pass 2 of my form inputs on the keyup of "username".  I would like to send "username" and "location" inputs to my php. Can this be done?  Tried a few things but can't figure it out.

Note: I would like to pass both when "username"is being typed.

Form:

```
<fieldset>
<input name="location" type="text" id="location" maxlength="15">
<label for="username">Enter Username :                                                                 
<input name="username" type="text" id="username" maxlength="15">                            
<span id="user-result"></span>                                      
</label>                                                                    
</div>                                                              
</fieldset>
```

script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#username").keyup(function (e) {

        //removes spaces from username
        //$(this).val($(this).val().replace(/\s/g, ''));
        var username = $(this).val();
        if(username.length < 4){$("#user-result").html('');return;}

        if(username.length >= 4){
            $("#user-result").html('<img src="../images/ajax-loader.gif" />');
            $.post('check.php', {'username':username}, function(data) {
              $("#user-result").html(data);
            });
        }
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Looks like you're sending `username` fine at the moment. Are you asking how to include another value named `location`?

Comment: you want to pass both when one is being typed? or both when either is being typed?

Comment: $.post('check.php', {"value_1":value_1, "value_2": value_2}, function(data) {
              $("#user-result").html(data);
            });

Comment: I would like to pass both when one is being typed.  Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: Just expand the array you're sending to your script, you're sending username fine

Comment: So by expanding the array do i just add to the post? ie. {'username':username,'location':location}

Comment: Yes, I recommend [reading this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Using_object_initializers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just get the value from of the location input inside the username `keyup` event handler and pass it along with the request:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#username").keyup(function (e) {

        //removes spaces from username
        //$(this).val($(this).val().replace(/\s/g, ''));

        var username = $(this).val();
        var location = $('#location').val();

        if(username.length < 4){$("#user-result").html('');return;}

        if(username.length >= 4){
            $("#user-result").html('<img src="../images/ajax-loader.gif" />');
            $.post('check.php', { 'username':username, 'location': location}, function(data) {
              $("#user-result").html(data);
            });
        }
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#username").on('keyup', function (e) {
        // grab the elements we're interested in
        var username = $(this).val(),
            location = $("#location").val();

        if (username.length > 3) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'check.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    username: username,
                    location: location
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    // do something after success
                    console.log(data)
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    // deal with the error
                    console.log('status: ' + textStatus);
                    console.log('error: ' + errorThrown);
                },
                dataType: 'json' // or change to whatever you want
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks Brent Barbata! It worked like a charm!  Thanks everyone else who reached out to help as well!